# react native animated : why my loop image animation is worked like a weird?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

[image]

i want to make loop animation
loop(
1.fade in image for 0.5sec
2.make image visible for 2.5sec
3.fade out image for 0.5sec
4.make image invisible for 2.5sec
)
but result is weird, i detect my image blink.

```
const fadeAni = useRef<Animated.Value>(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
useEffect(() => {
        Animated.loop(
            Animated.sequence([
                Animated.timing(fadeAni, {
                    toValue: 1,
                    duration: 500,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.delay(2500),
                Animated.timing(fadeAni, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration: 500,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.delay(2500),
            ]),
        ).start()
    }, [])


    return (
        <Animated.View style={{ opacity: fadeAni }}>
            <ImageBackground source={imageSource} style={styles.area}>
            </ImageBackground>
        </Animated.View>   
    );
```

what is problem of my code and how to i implement make a correct animation?

Comment: wait are you using reanimated or {Animated} from 'react-native

Comment: i use {Animated} from 'react-native'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, i got your issue, its because youre not passing the `fadeIn` dependency in useEffect.

```
const fadeAni = useRef<Animated.Value>(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
useEffect(() => {
        Animated.loop(
            Animated.sequence([
                Animated.timing(fadeAni, {
                    toValue: 1,
                    duration: 500,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.delay(2500),
                Animated.timing(fadeAni, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration: 500,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.delay(2500),
            ]),
        ).start()
    }, [fadeAni])


    return (
        <Animated.View style={{ opacity: fadeAni }}>
            <ImageBackground source={imageSource} style={styles.area}>
            </ImageBackground>
        </Animated.View>   
    );
```

Try now. ive tried it. please check [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/EYJ7WaxK4)